# while saving data form serverless node js to mongoDB, i am getting an error:-ObjectParameterError: Para obj" to Document() must be an object,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-serverless

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    dotenv.config()
    // connecting data base
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useFindAndModify: false,
   useCreateIndex: true
});
const User = require('../model/user')

   module.exports.register = async (req) => {
    try {

        await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
     
        const user = new User({req.body})
        await user.save()
        return {

            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
                message: "sign up success please login",
                data: user
            }))
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            meassage: "Something went wrong",
            debugInfo: err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true,
    },
    email:{
       type:String,
       trim:true,
       required:true
    },
    hashed_password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    salt:String, //randomly generated complicated string
    created:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    updated:Date

})

Comment: You have a lot of room to improve. You posted some code and didn't explain what it did. Also, you didn't format your code either.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `const user = new User({req.body})`
to `const user = new User(req.body)`

and try it

Comment: Could you share with me user model  and input data ( req.body)  ?